# chose a specific python file to run in Fast API

Tags: python, fastapi

I have 2 files in a folder named "pyproj"

1. main.py
2. post.py

[folder path image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MucX.png)

whenever I run the localhost with uvicorn, main.py is only shown in the local host browser.

In post.py I have the app instance as "app", so I run the uvicorn in terminal as

`uvicorn main:app --reload`

In post.py I have the app instance as "app2", so I run the uvicorn in terminal as

`uvicorn post:app2 --reload`

no matter what code I run from the above I can see only the main.py's paths. Can someone help with this.

Comment: This is not likely to happen if what you explained is the case. I clearly see separate list of APIs from main.py and post.py using respective commands  as you suggested. 
Do you have distinc set of apis in respective files that you can compare with api doc in http://localhost:8000/docs   ?

Comment: Add relevant code that shows the issue together with relevant requests that show the problem to your question.